# Daily Table out of Start and End Date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a calculated table with daily information of employees based on MIN and MAX dates. I'm on Power BI.

[image: main and output table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be super-efficient if you have too many employees and dates, but you can take the cartesian product of the list of employees with the list of all possible days and filter that down:

```
CalculatedTable =
VAR CartesianProduct =
    CROSSJOIN (
        VALUES ( Main[employee_number] ),
        CALENDAR ( MIN ( Main[start] ), MAX ( Main[end] ) )
    )
RETURN
    FILTER (
        CartesianProduct,
        [Date] >= LOOKUPVALUE ( Main[start], Main[employee_number], [employee_number] ) &&
        [Date] <= LOOKUPVALUE ( Main[end],   Main[employee_number], [employee_number] )
    )
```

The `CALENDAR` function generates a table with column `Date` starting from the first argument and includes all days up to the second argument.

---

I'm not sure how to do this more efficiently in DAX, but I can think of a cleaner solution in M (query editor language).

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks! I cant access M-query right now which is why I had to think of this alternative :D